# How can I change the option value in the td by beautiful

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

With this code:

```python
def getTD_byText1(text):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(r"D:\testData\test.htm"))
    div_=soup.find('div',attrs={'id':'CONTROL_VideoAdapter_MultiSelect'})
    for input in div_.findAll('input',attrs={'name':'CID_CONTROL_VideoAdapter_MultiSelect'}):
        #print input
        td=input.find_parent()
        td_text=td.get_text().strip()
        #print td
        if td_text.find(text)>0:
            print td.find_previous_sibling()
            drp=td.find_previous_sibling()
drp=getTD_byText1('A3WJ'）
```

I get the element:

```html
<td width="1%">
  <select class="interactiveSelectAction" id="interactiveSelectControl" name="CID_CONTROL_VideoAdapter_MultiSelect_QTY" size="1">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

How can I change the option value in the `td`, and when I change the value, the new value will be shown on the html?